Blender z depth pass output is darkened after normalization
In blender 4.2 on windows10 ,I've tried to render a depth image following instructions on the Internet. But my results are different in window layout and output image.
In layout:

While the render output is:

This is a bug in Blender 4.2:
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/124950
In Cycles background has 1000000000 depth, while EEVEE it is limited to camera Clip End distance which is 100 by default. So the walk-around is to set a large camera Clip End value, 10000 is enough:


What is also strange is, after normalize node, the depth values should be mapped in 0~1. However, with color_mode=BW and color_depth=16bit, the background color value  is 50178 not 65535(white).

What's more, I also wonder what length unit z-buffer uses for float numbers.
